# create management subclass give errors

Tags: swift, core-data

If I go to editor > create management subclass and then let Xcode generate a subclass I always get errors.

What am I doing wrong here that I always get these errors?

```
extension Passport { //'Passport' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Passport> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Passport>(entityName: "Passport") //'Passport' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
    }

    @NSManaged public var passportId: String? //@NSManaged only allowed on an instance property or method
    @NSManaged public var person: Person? //@NSManaged only allowed on an instance property or method
}
```

How can is fix those errors or what do i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the entity codegen to not to class definition but to Manual/None.[image]

This configuration is the default Codegen configuration when you create an entity in the data model editor. With this configuration, Xcode will automatically generate the required NSManagedObject subclass as part of the project’s derived data.